# Why Rational Numbers do not include pairs $(a,b)$ with $b=0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X=Z\times Z$

If we have the relation $R$ on $X$ defined by $(a,b)R(c,d)$ if and only if $ad=bc$. Then, what is the problem if $b=0$?

Obviously, I'm not looking for the answer that we cannot divide by 0, but rather something more fundamental. I thought that perhaps it violates the reflexivity of the equivalence relation.

Can I have a hint?

Comment: Relation $R$ on $R$? Don't you mean on $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @GitGud I think he means that we are looking at the field of fractions of a commutative ring $R$.

Comment: @Johanna Even if he is, the phrase "relation $R$ on $R$" has a syntax error in that one of the $R$s should be something else.

Comment: @True. It is not great language, but I was clarifying that this refers to a general commutative ring, it is not restricted to $\mathbb{Z}$. Still, it should be edited in the question.

Answer (score 6):

$(1, 0)R(0, 0)$ and $(0, 0)R(0, 1)$, but $(1, 0)\not R(0, 1)$.  Thus, $R$ fails to be an equivalence relation without that restriction (not transitive).

Answer (score 2):

As anorton said, this fails to be an equivalence relation when you include $(0,0)$. 
You don't need to throw away all ordered pairs with $b=0$, though; you could just remove $(0,0)$, then get a valid equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. You could think of these as the "extended rationals," $\mathbb Q\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: Is there a way to define division by a representation of $\infty$ and get an infinitesimal instead of 0?

Comment: Why is it only $(0,0)$? Why would it be impossible to define $(0,0)R(0,0)$?